# Check if a List contains one or more values of another List

Tags: dart

How can we do this in Dart:

```
List<String> text= ["This", "is", "very", "nice"];

List<String> search1= ["This"]; 
List<String> search2= ["very", "is"]; 
List<String> search3= ["This", "is", "great"]; 

print(text.contains(search1)); // true
print(text.contains(search2)); // true
print(text.contains(search3)); // false
```

since the results of the code above are always "false":
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/73f7c386cbb7246c617712c390d4dbb1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Set.intersection()

```
List<String> text = ["This", "is", "very", "nice"];

List<String> search1 = ["This"];
List<String> search2 = ["very", "is"];
List<String> search3 = ["This", "is", "great"];

print(text.toSet().intersection(search1.toSet()).length == search1.length); // true
print(text.toSet().intersection(search2.toSet()).length == search2.length); // true
print(text.toSet().intersection(search3.toSet()).length == search3.length); // false
```